# Async Dart function is not working properly

Tags: function, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I've created two functions. I want that when the first one is completed `count()` the `text()` function will be executed. But it's not working as expected. Where is the problem?

```
Future<void> count() async {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () => print(i));
    }
  }

 Future<void> text()  async{
    print("Done");
 }
  
  

void main()  {
  count().then((value)  {
     text();
  });

  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to await the Future.delayed and you also need to change the Duration to 1 second:

```
Future<void> count() async {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print(i));
    }
  }

 Future<void> text()  async{
    print("Done");
 }
  
  

void main() async  {
 count().then((value)  {
     text();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `await` the `Future.delayed` as it is an asynchronous function.

```
Future<void> count() async {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () => print(i));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Done
```

Answer (score 1):

when there is something future and you use async you must use await in the body with future methods

```
Future<void> count() async {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print(i)); // here 
    }
  }

 Future<void> text()  async{
    print("Done");
 }
  
  

void main() async  {
 count().then((value)  {
     text();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way to wait for all the delayed futures, is to use `Future.wait`:

```dart
Future<void> count() =>
  Future.wait([for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: i), () => print(i))]);

void main() async {
  await count();
  print("Done");
}
```

This starts all the delayed operations, then waits for *all* of them.

This generalizes to cases where the operations do not necessarily complete in the order they are started.

Using `Future.wait` is the way to wait for a number of parallel asynchronous operations, instead of waiting for each individually.